# how to run jquery code properly in a php loop

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

i have a code sample to like the posts
i put the proper picture with the jquery code, but when I press the loadmore button show all the pictures same! .li_ik1 or .li_ik2

http://s8.picofile.com/file/8346985692/as.png

another problem is that when i click on an image, a query line is added to mysql, but on any other click on like, just the same as the first one will be imported several times.

this is a1.php:

```
<div  id="comnts2"></div>
<button id="btn2" style="width: 300px;height: 40px;position: relative;left:80px;background-color:aliceblue;font-size: 18px;border: solid  1px #9EBDFC;border-radius: 20px;top: 20px">load more</button>


<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

  var comco2 = 2;
  var offset2 = 0;

  $("#btn2").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
       url: "a2.php",
        data: { comnco2: comco2, offset2: offset2 }
      })
      .done(function(msg2) {
        $("#comnts2").append(msg2);
      });
    offset2 = offset2 + comco2;
  });

  $("button").trigger("click");
});
</script>
```

this is a2.php:

```
$comnco2=$_POST['comnco2'];
$offset2=$_POST['offset2'];
$uid=1;
$zps=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `tbl_users_posts` WHERE uid =1 limit $offset2,$comnco2");while($rzp=mysqli_fetch_assoc($zps)){
    $pid=$rzp['id'];
    $lik=$rzp['lik'];?>

<div><?php echo $pid;?></div>
<?php $sclk=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM t_plik WHERE pid='$pid' AND uid='$uid'");
    $nmlk=mysqli_num_rows($sclk);?>
<span class="ic_lk"></span>

<script>
$('document').ready(function(){
    var lik= <?php echo $nmlk;?>;
    var uid= <?php echo $uid;?>;
    var pid= <?php echo $pid;?>;
if(lik==0) {
        $('.ic_lk').html('<img class="li_ik1" src="pc3/up.png"></img>'); 
        }else if(lik>0){
        $('.ic_lk').html('<img class="li_ik2" src="pc3/uup.png"></img>'); 
    }

$(document).on("click", ".li_ik1",function(){
    $(this).replaceWith('<img class="li_ik2" src="pc3/uup.png"/>');
    });
$(document).on("click", ".li_ik2",function(){
    $(this).replaceWith('<img class="li_ik1" src="pc3/up.png"/>');
    });


    $(".li_ik1").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
       url: "b1.php",
        data: { uid: uid, pid: pid }
      });
  });
}); 
</script>

<?php }?>
```

and this is b1.php:

```
$uid=$_POST['uid'];
$pid=$_POST['pid'];
$inlk=mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO t_plik (uid,pid) VALUES ($uid,$pid)");
```

how can i fix this?
thanks

Comment: PHP cannot run jQuery in a loop.  PHP runs on the server, jQuery runs on the client.

Comment: ok, how should i do it?

Comment: Best thing would be to do this with [AJAX](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming))

Comment: i do use the ajax! for what part i should use the ajax?

Comment: for which part i should use ajax?

Comment: i need just how to send each one of the  post ids to b2.php